# Where can I find Cardano implementation repository?

Tags: development

For [Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) and [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) I can easily find repositories with their implementations.
Where is an equivalent for that for Cardano?
I have found this [repository](https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-node) but I am confused by the name of the owner of this repository (I heard about Emurgo, IOHK and Foundation but not about IntersectMBO) so I am not sure if that's what I am looking for(?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cardano node is composed of numerous components including:

- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-base
- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-ledger/
- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/ouroboros-network/
- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/ouroboros-consensus/
- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-api/
- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-cli/
- https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-node/

Comment: Ok, so I assume that if I am looking for the "core" Cardano functionality then I should go with cardano-node most likely.

Comment: If you are looking for the core functionality you should probably look at `ledger` and/or `consensus`.

Answer (score 1):

Intersect is the cardano members based organization launched last year. Think of it like the Linux foundation equivalent for supporting Cardano development.

Comment: Ok, so my confusion about IntersectMBO was unnecessary :) There are a lot of organizations around Cardano...